# Simple mod_rewrite rule.....?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a edit page that looks at record_id's in the url.. I don't want the user to see any record id, that way they can't replace it with another and edit another record....

Anyways, my url is like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder_detail_edit.php?recordID=3980
```

I would like it to just display:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/folder_detail_edit.php
```

Is this possible regardless of the recordID???

Comment: But then, how would you know what the recordID was supposed to be? If you don't want someone to edit another ID, you should put some kind of authentication up.

Comment: Know that whatever you do with the URL, regardless of which HTTP method or whatever you use, it is ALWAYS possible (even easy) for the user to replace the record ID with another. So you __must__ do some sort of authentication on the server to check whether the user should be allowed to edit that record.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on hiding the ID as a security mechanism. Your server side code should be comparing the ID against the logged in user to ensure they have the correct privileges to access that record.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the http post method to send this data to the server, this way, it won't be visible in the url.
Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: That wouldn't stop them from replacing it though, easy to bypass.

Answer (score 0):

The central problem is not that the record ID is visible and thus can be replaced but that your application allows your users to modify all records. That’s an authorization problem. And hiding the ID does not solve that since the record has to be identified somehow.

You should better implement some authorization mechanism so that your users can only access and modify those records that they are allowed to.

Comment: Great feedback. I will initiate a Registration module!